# How can I get rid of hackers in Halo 1 PC?

Tags: pc, halo-combat-evolved

I've played Halo 1 PC for a while now. I enjoy playing in CTF and Slayer using the internet. But I've been getting frustrated about people using hacks to kill people easily, or using the hack that makes people shoot the head easier. Even more frustrated when someone uses a hack that makes everyone die in the game and switch teams. 
Though I don't get as frustrated when someone only gets kills by running over people, or using the banshee way too much, sometimes I feel like they should get out of the game. 
So I was wondering if there is a way to get rid of these types of players.

Answer (score 6):

As with most games, if the game's security is not up to the task of blocking unscrupulous players, the only option is to avoid playing on public servers and just play on private servers or with friends.

Answer (score 6):

To elaborate on Macha's answer, the only way to rid the game of cheaters is to fix the game, and that's up to the game manufacturer. Considering that this particular game we're talking about was released in 2001, it's unlikely that Microsoft or Bungie would release one at this point.

Comment: I have been kicked out of games by the host (sometimes because they think I'm cheating by using bot, which I don't) a few times. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: @UnKnown hosts normally are allowed to kick players, but most of the time you can rejoin after x time (say 10-20 mins)

Comment: As Viper_Sb said, yes, the host can kick you out of the game. That doesn't mean that they're not allowed to join back to the game or any other host's game, for that matter.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually kick/ban them if you are the Host.

http://hce.halomaps.org/index.cfm?nid=314

Commands:

- sv_ban [cheater]
- sv_ban_penalty 5m 1h 1d 1w [perma]
- sv_banlist
- sv_unban [innocent]

Comment: So how do you make those commands work?

Comment: Type them into the console if you are running a dedicated server.

Comment: Does this work on Halo 1 Demo? (The one you can download free.)

Comment: No, this is for the dediservers. If you have admin rights just type them in the console.